# Comment life-span

Tags: discussion, comments

Should a comment pointing to a necessary edit on OP's post be deleted after the appropriate action has been taken and the answer edited?

For example:

OP writes in his answer:

> pritn('Hello World!')

But clearly there is a typo there (**pritn** instead of **print**), so someone writes a comment pointing that out. OP (or whoever else) edits the post, correcting the above mistake.

So my question is, should the comment be deleted?

Comment: Yes. If it's your own, you can delete it yourself. If it's someone else's, you can flag it as obsolete.

Comment: Flagging it seems too harsh given the description when mouse-overring the flag but OK. Thanks. Should i delete this comment now? XD

Comment: @Ev.Kounis What's actually _harsh_ in flagging something _obsolete_? There won't be any penalty for the commenter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when mouse-overring the flag it says: "flag this comment for serious problems or moderator attention". We are talking about the same flag, aren't we?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Well, deleteing obsolete comments involves a moderator action, that doesn't imply it's about a _serious problem_.